# AngularJS Typescript loop through appsettings JSON

Tags: angularjs, typescript

im having a really hard time looping through a specific section of the appsettings.json file i have. I am using angularjs with typescript any help would be greatly appreciated.

ServerConfig.ts

```
export interface ServerConfig {  
  campaigns: Campaign[];
}

export interface Campaign {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  enabled: boolean;
}
```

Appsettings.json

```
{
  "Settings": {    
    "Campaigns": [
      {
        "Title": "Test1",
        "Description": "This is test 1",
        "Enabled": true
      },
      {
        "Title": "Test2",
        "Description": "This is test 2",
        "Enabled": true
      }
    ],    
  },
}
```

Typescript

```
import { ServerConfig } from "../core/ServerConfig";

declare var config: ServerConfig;

export class IndexController {
  constructor(
  ) { }

  public $onInit() {

    var campaigns = config.campaigns;

    campaigns.forEach(function (data) {
      console.log(data.title);
    });

  }
}
export var home: ng.IComponentOptions = {
  controller: IndexController,
  templateUrl: "/app/index.html"
};
```

The error I get is "campaigns.forEach is not a function"

Comment: `campaigns
:
description
:
null
enabled
:
false
title
:
null` 
@Sajeetharan thats odd :/

Comment: `campaigns:{title: null, description: null, enabled: false}` to be more specific I dont think it picking up the inner part of campaigns as an array

Comment: yes that is obious because you have not assigned, why dont you use http.get and bind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem from what I can see is I didn't set it up correctly as an array.

ServerConfig.ts

```
export interface ServerConfig {
  campaigns: Campaign;
}

interface CampaignItem {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  enabled: boolean
}

interface Campaign extends Array<CampaignItem> { }
```